# API 31.0 breaking change in namespaced Visualforce $Setup global

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, customsetting, namespace

Has anyone encountered this problem when evaluating `$Setup` global variable in Visualforce?

If, **in an organization with a namespace prefix**, I have a hierarchy Custom Setting like the following,
it compiles and renders without exception, except that the output value is `null`

```
<!-- evaluates and outputs null -->
{!$Setup.Object__c.Field__c}
```

Now if I want the custom setting to resolve correctly, I have to fully qualify the Object Name and Field Name, and I believe this is new behaviour:

```
<!-- evaluates and outputs actual intended value -->
{!$Setup.namespace__Object__c.namespace__Field__c}
```

This means you can no longer use the same codebase in Development and Release environments... you would need to tokenize/replace the namespace prefix when deploying to the appropriate variant.

I've tried dynamically dereferencing the field: `$Setup['Object__c']['Field__c']` to no avail.

Any ideas what causes this regression and how we fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue your facing seems to be related to the following known issue which will be fixed in winter 15 release.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5P9AAK

Comment: I've deployed the codebase in question to a Winter '15 prerelease org and verified it does fix the need to overqualify those references. Thanks very much for contributing here.

Comment: Is this actually fixed? I seems to be broken in Spring '17. I'm getting default values back unless the namespace is explicitly included.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - Were you able to get a resolution on this? it doesn't seem to work for us as well, without hard namespace references.

Comment: @VarunC I'm using the fully qualified namespace on all the custom setting `$Setup` references. It may or may not be required, but with scratch orgs connected to a devhub where the namespace is registered it isn't an issue for me currently. That is to say, scratch orgs allowed me to work around the issue entirely, so I haven't really followed up on it.