# $Setup global merge field for checkbox hierarchy custom setting always returning false in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, customsetting

I have a hierarchy custom setting with a checkbox field on it.

The checkbox field defaults to false.

When managing the custom setting only the Default Organization Level Values are defined. There are no Profile or user level values.

Following the instructions from [$Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm) I added a merge field to access the value in Visualforce (v39.0):

```
<apex:page >
    <p>
        Direct:{! $Setup.App_Prefs__c.Show_Help_Content__c}
    </p>
    <p>
        Negated:{! !$Setup.App_Prefs__c.Show_Help_Content__c}    
    </p>
</apex:page>
```

When the setting is unchecked I get the expected output:

[image: False Visualforce output]

Yet when I check the custom setting I still get the same output?

I did a sanity check from anonymous Apex:

```
System.debug(App_Prefs__c.getInstance().Show_Help_Content__c);
```

> 17:04:43.6 (25436740)|USER_DEBUG|[1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm)|DEBUG|true

A SOQL query against `App_Prefs__c` shows only one record.

I'm sure I've got the field name correct because if I intentionally make it wrong I get back an "Field Foo__c does not exist. Check spelling." error on save.

---

It appears I need to explicitly use the namespace prefix defined in the packaging org to get the actual value.

This corresponds with the problem described in [API 31.0 breaking change in namespaced Visualforce $Setup global](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/47381/102). That question indicated it was resolved. Perhaps it has regressed in Spring '17?

Comment: Please also check value of `{NOT(!$Setup.App_Prefs__c.Show_Help_Content__c)}` in the page, NOT function instead of negation.

Comment: @RahulSharma I did try that variation but didn't include it in the question. `NOT(X)` and `!X` seemed to be equivalent as far as I could tell (as I'd expect them to be)

Comment: That's correct. Just wanted to be check. Thanks. Could be a bug as you've mentioned.